# How can i change the Django admin template on the fly

Tags: python, django

I have the Django Admin model like this

```
class STUDENTAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = "students/student_change_list.html"
```

Now i want to chnage that dynamically based on some request parameter
something like

```
if request.GET['foo']:
        change_list_template = "students/student_change_list_other.html"
```

how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to override the `changelist_view` and act on the `TemplateResponse()` returned from it or change the variable holding that name just before that call.

The original function is like this

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    # a lot of stuff happen here
    return TemplateResponse(request, self.change_list_template or [
        'admin/%s/%s/change_list.html' % (app_label, opts.object_name.lower()),
        'admin/%s/change_list.html' % app_label,
        'admin/change_list.html'
    ], context, current_app=self.admin_site.name)
```

so I think that a code like

```
def changelist(self, request, extra_context=None):
    if request.GET['foo']:
        self.change_list_template = "students/student_change_list_other.html"

    return super(STUDENTAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```